# Monthly event lister cutting off current day (PHP)

Tags: php, date

I have a little cms loading in events on a page of mine, it works great but the issue is that it is hiding the events when it is the day of them. Example being, there is an event on the 20th that was listed on the 19th, but on the 20th is disappears. I am trying to figure out how to change this so it disappears the day after instead. Here is the code.

```
<?php 
$monthsArray = Array(1=>"January",
                  2=>"February",
                  3=>"March",
                  4=>"April",
                  5=>"May",
                  6=>"June",
                  7=>"July",
                  8=>"August",
                  9=>"September",
                  10=>"October",
                  11=>"November",
                  12=>"December");
$monthCounter = 0;
$pastLoop=0;
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
while($obj=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
$monthTitle = NULL;
$currMonth = date("n", strtotime($obj->eventDate));
$class="class='month_$currMonth'";


if(date("n", strtotime($obj->eventDate)) != $pastLoop){
 $monthTitle = "<div class='monthTitle'>".$monthsArray[$currMonth]."</div>";

}
?>
```

Comment: can you post your sql query ?

Comment: forgive me, I don't normally work with these sorts of things, how can I provide this?